# Remove button border when entered

Tags: c#, button, toolstrip

When I hover over buttons on my C# form I have them highlighted yellow like how Microsoft office products but I don't want it to show the button border. I've seen people mention FlatStyle or FlatAppearance but it doesn't seem to recognize those commands. I'm looking into rendering now but I'm new to C# and I'm certain there must be a simple way to do it, It's not something I want to spend a lot of time on if possible.

I must stress I've been reading through books on windows forms programming and haven't found any answers its not that I'm lazy but I often find SO a very good source with really good input.

Tried this:

```
this.TSVehicleButton.BorderStyle = None;
```

Tried this:

```
this.TSVehicleButton.System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle = None;
```

I tried lots of things but didn't mention it as part of my question, I'm new to C# and didn't want to come across as stupid. People get a little bitchy when people put things that they tried and isn't right.

Comment: Are u using winforms?

Comment: Yeah I am @Sharad developing in VS05

Answer (score 3):

Use following on

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton()
        : base()
    {
        // Prevent the button from drawing its own border
        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // Draw Border using color specified in Flat Appearance
        Pen pen = new Pen(FlatAppearance.BorderColor, 1);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width - 1, Size.Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
    }
}
```

I might help you.

Comment: Cheers, I have noticed similar things in this book and I'm going to look into this, feels odd that the solution should be as complicated as this but I think thats because of the languages I'm used to.

Answer (score 2):

just use `this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;`

Answer (score 2):

Just set the following `Button` properties, for example at design time in the properties window:

```
FlatStyle=Flat
FlatAppearance.BorderSize=0
```

Or run the following code, for example for a button named `button1`:

```
button1.FlatStyle=True
button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize=0
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for me, and it's so simple!

```
button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); // transparent
button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```

Now the button has no borders, even when you enter the cursor. This worked perfectly on Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way of taking the border away from the button and its in the button properties.
First make sure you have clicked on the button so that the properties belong to the button.
on the properties pane go and find Flat Appearance and expand it by clicking on the + sign in front of it.
This will open more option for you, one of the option is border size which is set to 1, change this to 0,
Next, 3 lines below that there is a property called FlatStyle and its set to standard, this needs to be changed to Flat.
[Flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW88M.png)
Job done!

Hope this helps